# Where is the source code for apache hadoop examples

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Can anyone please direct me to the source code for Apache Hadoop Yarn examples. The 2.2.0 distribution comes with a jar names hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar. I am trying to find the source code for the examples.
Any pointer would be helpful...

Thanks,Amit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you look at the source code in SVN? Here it is.
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/

Comment: Sean Owen Thanks a lot for the info... Additionally can you please also mention how do I download the codes to my local eclipse. I have svn installed in my eclipse. I mean how do I connect to the svn repository using my eclipse

Comment: If you depend on this code as a Maven artifact it should automatically grab source code for you. Otherwise I don't know, add the source root to your project or something.

Answer (score 1):

Mirror link on Github (for Git users)

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SVN link to get the source code to your local machine.

You can install svn with the below command in Linux.

sudo apt-get install subversion

*svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples*